# 2D rectangular array into function

Tags: c

I have a 2D rectangular array `char rect_array [4][20]`,
where contents are defined by a user,
to be passed into a fixed function prototype as follows:

```
int findTarget (char *string, char *nameptr[], int num)
```

The following does not work, as in rect_array is underlined as error:

```
findTarget (user_input, rect_array, no_of_names);
```

Have tried etc:

```
rect_array[4][20]
&rect_array
rect_array[4]
```

May i know what went wrong? If the prototype has to be as mentioned? Do I change the array declaration?

Comment: 1). Pick a language. 2) Each row is fixed 20 chars wide?

Comment: what is the declaration of `rect_array`? is it `char *rect_array[4][20]` or `char rect_array[4][20]` ?

Comment: its rect_array[4][20]

Comment: the rect_array[4][20] should have a type what is the type ? is it char or char* ?

Comment: err, your question is not clear. You want to pass that array in `char *nameptr[]`?

Comment: im sorry for the lack of info. its char rect_array [4][20];

Comment: You have made an assumption that `char* array[]` is a valid parameter type for a 2D array. It is not.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Are you getting a compiler error?  Is the program running incorrectly?

Comment: try `char nameptr[4][20]` for argument in function declaration maybe? Your question is still very unclear. Rewrite your question.

Comment: C or C++? Pick _one_.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: its C. Question edited.

Comment: @brainsfrying: Well there goes all the _good_ solutions I was going to give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Per information added to the question, the OP cannot alter the function prototype, which must be:

```
int findTarget (char *string, char *nameptr[], int num)
```

This being the case, the only way to "pass" the 2D table to this function is via a temporary pointer array. Some fancy `malloc()`-ing would work, but in the end it would come down to this:

```
char data[4][20];
char *dataptrs[] = { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] };
char name[] = "name";

findTarget(name, dataptrs, sizeof(dataptrs)/sizeof(dataptrs[0]));
```

---

**Original post**

For a C solution with a fixed 20-char-length table:

```
int findTarget (const char *string, const char names[][20], size_t rows)
{
   // each row ("rows" count of them) is fixed at 20 chars wide.
   // ....
}
```

Or...

```
int findTarget (const char *string, const char (*names)[20], size_t rows)
{
   // each row ("rows" count of them) is fixed at 20 chars wide.
   // ....
}
```

Invoked as such:

```
char data[4][20];

findTarget("targetName", data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]));
```

---

Note: If your platform supports them (and almost all of them *do*) you can use VLAs (variable length arrays) in C to make the width an arbitrary parameter to the function as well:

```
int findTarget (const char *string, 
    size_t rows, size_t cols, 
    const char (*names)[cols])
{
   // each row ("rows" count of them) is variable to "cols" columns wide.
   // ....
}
```

Invoked as:

```
char data[4][[20];

findTarget("target", sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]), sizeof(data[0]), data);
```

Comment: thank you. Sorry however, what if the prototype has to be as edited. Do I change the declaration to char *rect_array [4][20]   ?

Comment: @brainsfrying *"what if the prototype has to be as edited"* I don't really know what that means. What is the prototype **now** ?? Your `*rect_array[4][20]` is *not* what you think it is. That declares a table of 80 `char *`.

Comment: The prototype has to be fixed as int findTarget (char *string, char *nameptr[], int num) Correct, i need a total of 80 chars.

Comment: @brainsfrying you cannot pass your declared array to that function with that prototype. That function is looking for *pointer* array. Your data is a fixed array of chars (that happens to be in two dimensions). If you cannot change the prototype you will have to populate a temporary char pointer array with the base address of each row in your table and pass that to the function. SO your prototype is fixed and cannot be altered?

Comment: you're rite.the prototype is not to be altered.